# AVR ATMEL ATMega168 libraries

Tags: c, avr, atmega

I am new to C and the AVR programming world, and therefore I am currently reading [this book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Make_AVR_Programming.html?id=y7C2AgAAQBAJ&source=kp_cover) about the topic.

The author makes reference to ATMEL libraries which deals with memory manipulation, time (sleep) functions and so on. See below an example:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
```

My question is, where can I find the documentation for this and other ATMEL libraries? Are they already built-in in the compiler or the development kit? How can I see the corresponding `.c` file for it?

Comment: now why on earth would you want to see AVR library source-code?? You would'nt understand half of it, anyway - Atmel is a company with decades of experience, their implementations probably are filled with buttloads of hardware-specific optimizations, most of which probably are impossible to understand without in-depth knowledge ...

Comment: @specializt I think that studying hardware-specific optimisations is precisely the idea of looking at these files. Even though I have been programming for 20 years now, I have had zero experience with hardware programming. Reading through these files can shed some light on what goes on underneath the abstraction these libraries offer.

Comment: Yes, thats also called "industrial espionage" if and only if the company hasnt released the sources yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing Atmel Studio you can find the headers here:

```
<Program Files>\Atmel\Studio\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\avr\include
```

Documentation is available on [the Atmel web-site](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__io.html).

Comment: headers arent "c files" but thanks for sharing anyway

Answer (score 1):

The file is located in the following folder if you installed `avr-libc` through `homebrew` on a Mac:

`/usr/local/Cellar/avr-libc/[version]/avr/include/avr/io.h`